# Create encrypted text file in Android

Tags: android

I've a txt file in my /data/data/com.Myapp/file and I'd like to encrypt this txt and create other txt file. Using java in netBeans, I can do this, but with Android I've little problems to open the txt file and create another text file encrypted

I've a class encrypt

```
 public void Inicia(){
    this.c = getApplicationContext();
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        String key = "squirrel123"; // needs to be at least 8 characters for DES
        File file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath() + "/WhiteList.txt"); // original file
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        File file2 = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath() + "/teste.txt"); // create file encrypted
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file2, true);
        encrypt(key, fis, fos);
```

my problem is create the "teste.txt", I can't create this file

my code works fine in java app, but in Android I've this problems. Open the txt file and create a new

Comment: Why are you doing this at all?  If its for security-  anything in data/data/myapp can only be read with myapp, unless the user roots their device.  So no encryption is necessary.  If you're worried about rooters, then the encryption is useless anyway since the key is in plaintext in your app.

Comment: send this txt to my ftp server

only increase more the security